# 0/unconfirmed and now no transactions anymore

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, zero-confirmation

So recently (2days ago) I made this transaction:

```
Status: 0/unconfirmed, in memory pool
Date: 20.12.2017 23:30
To: N**** 1LecRzTpKXh9kCgqXbUXtdXfQjE145BR87
Debit: -0.00447735 BTC
Transaction fee: -0.00003840 BTC
Net amount: -0.00451575 BTC
Transaction ID: 850a72da35784c22c7fe1e39ac51cdc639923b26ab8bf7322f3cb7af4ffed263
Transaction total size: 191 bytes
Output index: 0
```

As you can see, the Bitcoins weren't sent and according to the Transaction ID the transaction wasn't done, as you can see here:
https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/tx/850a72da35784c22c7fe1e39ac51cdc639923b26ab8bf7322f3cb7af4ffed263/

So now I started to look around in different posts to get my coins back.
I found a post with the same problem... it told me to start Bitcoin Core like this:

```
E:\Programme\Bitcoin\bitcoin-qt.exe -zapwallettxes
```

but now i dont see my transactions anymore and i have 0 BTC in my balance.

I have no clue what to do now and how I can get my BTCs again.

Comment: Was the transaction suppose to deposit Bitcoins at your address?

Comment: Have you tried to do a E:\Programme\Bitcoin\bitcoin-qt.exe -rescan to force a rescan of all your transactions?

Comment: Thanks the -rescan solved the first Problem so now i see my transactions agian but still with 0/unconfimed, in memory pool. And no the transaction wasnt supposed to deposit bitcoins at my own addres its suppost to pay on a website.

Comment: You transaction fee is too low, it will probably never confirm. [You have a few options](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it)

Comment: Did you have a transaction problem? We have the same problem! Tell me how you solved it?

Answer (score -1):

I have observed from other experts that if you 'abandon transaction' your data will eventually be forgotten by other nodes and return to your account. You can 'abandon transaction' from the GUI console in 'transactions' by right clicking on it and selecting 'abandon'. This might take some time as even one outdated node might re-broadcast it again and it will get picked up by other nodes. Patience is what I have read. From there delete mempool and restart.

Comment: The Problem is i dont have the Transaction anymore its not there...

Comment: Ok now i have my transactions back but i cant press abandon transaction... probably because its in memory pool already